# 'npx create-react-app [name] --template typescript' error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

This is the error I get:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nXn0.jpg]

Literally, a few minutes ago I was able to create projects with "npx create-react-app [NAME] --template typescript" ... now I get this error. I've tried updating node.js, removing the node_modules folder, and other things but nothing's working. I'm a new developer so I try not to ask too many questions but this is really frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this might not be a true fix, but rather a workaround:

In your created app folder, open package.json file.

Change `react-scripts` and `typescript` versions, to:

```
"react-scripts": "3.4.4",
"typescript": "^3.2.1",
```

Next, remove `package.lock.json`, `yarn.lock`, `node_modules` and `tsconfig.json`.
Run `$ npm install` and then `$ npm start` should work normally.

Note that here we are using an older version of `react-scripts`.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! Do you know why Typescript sudden stopped working? Did they update recently and the dependency files are all over the place or something?

Comment: @RobinOrlando I have no idea. I updated to the newest OSX (BigSur), maybe that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this and for me running the command with `yarn` worked but the command with `npx` did not. Might be worth trying.